# Original author prefers code in their formatting style after I made edits to my style

Tags: support, comments, etiquette, code-formatting

I used to re-format script as part of my participation in Stack Overflow. I got surprised this morning with a comment reply under a recently edited answer (which I have formatted) saying:

> . . . Please do not do me any "favors" by reformatting my queries. I
>   format queries in my answers pretty much exactly the way that I want
>   them to be written. I am very particular about my formatting and do
>   not want it changed.

I do not mind to stop doing *favors* even though I never looked at it as a favour.

However, the tone of the request is impolite and does not provide any real reason *I am very particular about my formatting* is not a reason from my point of view.

The problem is, should I now remember this user and every time I want to reformat an answer I should make sure it's not from the same author?

Is there anyway to block them so I won't see their posts? Is the original author right to request this of me? What can I do about it?

**Update**
I asked a question for help how to deal with the issue. I did not reply to the comment above because I do not know if there are formatting rules other than what I know (e.g. my formats are being reviewed and approved before they appear). I am not in competition here to prove I am right. In fact, I did not claim any righteous. I simply asked if there is simpler  way to stop reformatting certain person's posts than checking the name (e.g. highlight or block ... etc.). I did not mention the name of the commenter, neither did claim my format was perfect. **I am abide by SO rules not people moods and opinions. And I have not transgressed any.**

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy he is of  134K reputation!!!

Comment: @hawk One can be needlessly pissy regardless of one's reputation.

Comment: Given that you cannot even format a quotation correctly I wouldn't be surprised if he got upset with your edits. If a code snippet isn't terribly unreadable in its current state (e.g. all on one line, or *not* formatted like code), maybe you should avoid editing it after all.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I suggest you go to my profile and look at all my formats. Before you judge I mentioned in my question that I format scripts (sql) using professional website. Thanks for the encouragement anyway!

Comment: Cool, except you did *not* mention in your question that you used any tools to format your scripts. And I'm sorry, but if you cannot format your own content correctly, I would not trust you to be editing other people's content either. That's just how it works.

Comment: @hawk: I've now looked at that specific example -- there was no need to reformat that, and I would have rejected that as "too minor". However, the borderline rude comments weren't needed. BTW, [here's the specific post in question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925824/output-a-record-that-appears-more-than-x-times/21925941#21925941).

Comment: I saw the revision in question (which I won't link to here - it's easy enough to find in any case). Your edit was, at best, questionable. You decreased the quality of the formatting in at least one way. I don't find the user's response impolite, given that context.

Comment: If all you're doing is reformatting how the SQL looks please stop. Now. Changing the spacing is _not_ a worthwhile edit (unless it goes off the page) and if you're one of those people who think that keywords in capitals make things clearer I will revert your edits. I'm sorry, that this seems like I agree but if they have 134k then I know who they are and they _always_ format their posts fine.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I'm sorry but you linked wrong post. The format wasn't mine. However, you highlighted that the person is requesting the same from other.

Comment: @hawk: It's not the post you were referring to, but you did in fact edit that post as well. It was just rolled back by another user. See [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21925941/revisions)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: indeed, sorry. The post I meant to link to is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925552/bom-query-with-hierarchyid/21925760#21925760).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's really quite easy - just think twice before hitting that edit button. You don't need special filters to fix this - just look at the post and see who the author is. Before you edit ask yourself:

- Does my proposed edit actually improve or add value to the post?
- Is the current formatting unreadable?
- Or is it just me?

If you find yourself having to think about it then it's just you.

I wouldn't consider the request as illustrated to be impolite, just unexpected.

Comment: I format SQL scripts and many of these scripts due to (I wanna answer first) are not formatted at all. I do check if they are readable or not. But I've never had to check the posters name. Why should I start consider unprofessional request here?

Comment: You've made the assumption that your edit was good and that the request that you stop is unprofessional @hawk. Take a second out to reconsider whether your edit was actually good. _If_ the edit wasn't is the request still unprofessional?

Comment: @ben: Of course it is. According to my observations every human takes any form of criticism as unprofessional, whether or not it is constructive and/or warranted.